# Traefik 2.0 Path Router Rule Not Working Without Host Rule

Tags: docker-swarm, traefik

I have a container running on my docker swarm which needs to be accessed at `/whoami` for all domain requests to my docker swarm. If I set up my routing rule in docker as...

```
traefik.http.routers.whoami-http.rule='Host(`www.example.com`) && Path(`/whoami`)'
```

The the routing is successfully and correctly done, but if I remove the Host() condition of the rule it no longer works. I have also tried using...

```
traefik.http.routers.whoami-http.rule='Host(`*`) && Path(`/whoami`)'
```

In case a wild card is neded but that doesn't work either. It seems that unless I add the Host condition to the rule then the Path condition doesn't work but a check of https://docs.traefik.io/routing/routers/#rule which has a list of all the rule checkers (conditions) supported shows that Path is a condition checker thats available with no mention of requiring a host condition checker.

Comment: the wild card doesn't work for me also. maybe `HostRegexp()` might work with correct regex format. without digging deeper, I found a simple solution. `rule: "PathPrefix('/')"`. in your case just `rule: "PathPrefix('/whoami')"` might work